# Adding text to each subplot in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, subplot

I am making bar graphs in seaborn and I want to add some text to each subplot.  I know how to add text to the entire figure, but I want to access each subplot and add text.  I am using this code:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

sns.set_style("whitegrid")

col_order=['Deltaic Plains','Hummock and Swale', 'Sand Dunes']

g = sns.FacetGrid(final, col="Landform", col_wrap=3,despine=False, sharex=False,col_order=col_order)

g = g.map(sns.barplot, 'Feature', 'Importance')

[plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45) for ax in g.axes.flat]

for ax, title in zip(g.axes.flat, col_order):
    ax.set_title(title)

g.fig.text(0.85, 0.85,'Text Here', fontsize=9) #add text
```

which gives me this:
[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

During your for loop you already have each subplot available to you with `ax`.

```
for ax, title in zip(g.axes.flat, col_order):
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.text(0.85, 0.85,'Text Here', fontsize=9) #add text
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Figure objects define `axes` property to access the Axes objects defined on it, another way to access the subplots is through the Figure object defined on the FacetGrid.

```py
for ax in g.fig.axes:
    ax.text(0.85, 0.85,'Text Here', fontsize=9)
```

If the FacetGrid is the current figure instance, then the following works too.

```py
for ax in plt.gcf().axes:
    ax.text(0.85, 1.85,'Text Here', fontsize=9)
```