# Add Text from Dataframe to Seaborn relplot

Tags: python, pandas, text, seaborn, subplot

I'm trying to add text from a dataframe, specifically the percentage difference between 2 periods in a dataset, to a seaborn relplot with multiple sub plots.

I've created an executable example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

#create dataframe 
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 200)
data = {'PTID': [11111, 11111, 11111, 11111, 22222, 22222, 22222, 22222, 33333, 33333, 33333, 33333, 44444, 44444, 44444, 44444, 55555, 55555, 55555, 55555],
        'Period' : ['Baseline','p1','p2','p3','Baseline','p1','p2','p3','Baseline','p1','p2','p3',  'Baseline','p1','p2','p3', 'Baseline','p1','p2','p3'] ,    
        'ALK PHOS': [46.0, 94.0, 21.0, 18.0, 56.0, 104.0, 31.0, 12.0, 50.0, 100.0, 33.0, 18.0, 46.0, 94.0, 21.0, 18.0, 46.0, 94.0, 21.0, 18.0],
        'AST (SGOT)': [33.0, 92.0, 19.0, 25.0, 33.0, 92.0, 21.0, 11.0, 33.0, 102.0, 18.0, 17.0, 23.0, 82.0, 13.0, 17.0, 23.0, 82.0, 13.0, 17.0],
        '% Saturation- Iron': [34.0, 65.0, 10.0, 14.0, 34.0, 65.0, 10.0, 14.0, 34.0, 65.0, 10.0, 14.0, 34.0, 65.0, 10.0, 14.0, 34.0, 65.0, 10.0, 14.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#melt into long format 
dfm = df.melt(id_vars=['PTID','Period'], var_name='Metric',value_name='Value')

#get average of data for period
dfg = dfm.groupby(['PTID','Period', 'Metric'])['Value'].mean().reset_index()

#drop periods in between, only keep first and last 
dfd = dfm[dfm['Period'].isin(['Baseline','p3'])]

#create dataframe with % difference between periods 
dfdg = dfd.groupby(['Metric', 'Period'])['Value'].mean().reset_index()
dfp = pd.pivot(dfdg, values='Value', index=['Metric'],
                    columns=['Period']).reset_index()
dfp['Difference'] = ((dfp['p3'] - dfp['Baseline'])/dfp['Baseline'])*100
dfp = dfp.round(2)

#plot subplots
p = sns.relplot(data=dfd, col='Metric', x='Period', y='Value', hue = 'PTID',kind='scatter', col_wrap=5, marker='o', palette='tab10',facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': True},)
p.map(sns.lineplot, 'Period', 'Value',  linestyle='--', color='gray', ci = None)

#add % change text to subplots 
for row in dfp['Difference']:
    print(row)
    p.fig.text(0.5,0.5, str(row) + "%",fontsize=12)
```

The problem I'm having, which you'll see if you run the code, is that it's not iterating through the subplots when adding the text and placing it all on the last plot. Where as, whet I'm trying to achieve is the % difference per

```
dfp["difference"]
```

for the specific metric on each subplot.

I tried following this existing example of a similar problem - [Adding text to each subplot in seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511334/adding-text-to-each-subplot-in-seaborn)

but the code is not executable and am having trouble with the "zip" function.

This is how I tried implementing the "zip" function:

```
#add % change text to subplots 
for idx, row in zip(g.axes,dfp['Difference']):
    print(row)
    p.fig.text(0.5,0.5, str(row) + "%",fontsize=12)
```

I know the axes won't help me but I'm not sure how to access the subplots.

Comment: You're not using `zip` in your example. Exactly what kind of trouble are you having? `p.fig` is the figure. The example reference is looping through the figure's Axes objects

Comment: Updated in the question.

Comment: Thanks @JohanC, unfortunately it did not work... unless I missed something. I tried ```for ax, row in zip(g.axes.flat,dfp['Difference']):
    ax.text(0.5,0.5, str(row) + "%",fontsize=12)```

Comment: in your code, the grid handle is named `p` instead of `g`

Comment: Correct @tdy, I wasn't aware of that standard. Changing it to g doesn't make a difference though. Could be anything really.

Comment: Sorry @JohanC, I see what you mean! It is actually working, kind of, the issue now is just the positioning of the text. They're printing below the subplots., which is why I missed the first time around.

Comment: `for ax, row in zip(p.axes.flat,dfp['Difference']):  ax.text(...., transform=ax.transAxes)` if you want to plot relative to the rectangle forming the axes.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you @JohanC :) That's a lot of hoops to jump though just to add some text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `ax` was not being specified in the for loop to add the text. This issue was fixed by changing the for loop to:

```
#add % change text to subplots 
for ax, row in zip(g.axes.flat,dfp['Difference']):
    ax.text(0.75,0.75, str(row) + "%",fontsize=12,transform=ax.transAxes)
```

Another important thing to note is that `transform=ax.transAxes` must be added so that the text is plotted relative to the axis.